# Angular 2 - How to implement a decorator in this specific case

Tags: angularjs, angular, decorator

I am very used to CDI decorators in JEE world, I would like to do something similar, I have this:

```
export abstract class AbstractCrudComponent<T> {
    save(entity: T) { ... }
}
```

I would like to create a decorator to implement specific logic in all implementations of subtypes of `User`, just before the final implementation of  `save` method be called, something like that:

```
export abstract class UserDecorator<T extends User> extends AbstractCrudComponent<T> {

    constructor(private delegate: AbstractCrudService)        

    save(entity: T) {
        //do stuff
        delegate.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Is the a way to accomplish that?